# MPI_Init failing in FreeBSD 13

Tags: c, mpi, freebsd, mpich

I'm using FreeBSD 13, and trying to compile (successfully) and run (un-succesfully) a simple minimal MPI program

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int res;

    res = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    if (res != MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "MPI_Init failed!\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    res = MPI_Finalize();
    if (res != MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "MPI_Finalize failed!\n");
        exit (0);
    }
}
```

I'm using `mpich-3.4.2_2` MPI library, compile the above with `mpicc example_mpi.c`, then run with `mpirun -np 2 ./a.out`.

Compiler is

> FreeBSD clang version 11.0.1 (git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git llvmorg-11.0.1-0-g43ff75f2c3fe)
> Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd13.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /usr/bin

I'm getting a strange MPI init error

> Abort(268484367) on node 0 (rank 0 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
> MPIR_Init_thread(153):  gpu_init failed
> [unset]: write_line error; fd=-1 buf=:cmd=abort exitcode=268484367
> :
> system msg for write_line failure : Bad file descriptor
> MPI_Init failed!

Any idea what is going on? I ran under root and same issue.

Comment: It looks like it is trying to start up a GPU - `gpu_init failed`. Do you have a GPU? Was the MPI library compiled with GPU support?

Comment: @DavidHenty I have a GPU, although I didn't compile the MPI library, I simply installed it with `pkg install mpich`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to have been a bug, I just saw it was fixed by FreeBSD folks.

See https://cgit.freebsd.org/ports/commit/?id=fd490a171c3da0d7bcb9a5f3ee3b4b46075dfa9e